# change div border after render Canvasjs chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvasjs

Im using the Canvasjs chart (http://canvasjs.com) I want to after the chart is render color of div border change to red

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height:300px; width:90%; font-family:BMitra; text-align:center; border: 1px solid black;"></div>

<script>
    function charting() {
        var dataPo = [];
        $.getJSON("<?=base_url();?>report/messages/create_report2", function(data) {
            for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPo.push({ label: data[i].label, y: data[i].y });
            }
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                //backgroundColor: "#D2FEFF",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                theme: "theme3",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title:{
                    text:"my title",
                    fontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                axisY:{
                    labelFontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                axisX:{
                  labelFontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                toolTip:{
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontFamily: "BYekan",
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints : dataPo,
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is missing a few closed brackets.

Then, according to [this docs](http://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/callback-function-for-render/), CanvasJS doesn't provide any callback handle for the `render()` function, but they say since it's very fast you probably won't have any issue in calling a function right after it.

This means you can change the border color with a jQuery call like this

```
$("yourDivSelector").css("border-color", "red");
```

and place it right after `chart.render();`. Your final code should look like this

```
<script>
    function charting() {
        var dataPo = [];
        $.getJSON("<?=base_url();?>report/messages/create_report2", function(data) {
            for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPo.push({ label: data[i].label, y: data[i].y });
            }
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                //backgroundColor: "#D2FEFF",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                theme: "theme3",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title:{
                    text:"my title",
                    fontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                axisY:{
                    labelFontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                axisX:{
                  labelFontFamily: "BYekan"
                },
                toolTip:{
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontFamily: "BYekan",
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints : dataPo,
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
            $("yourDivSelector").css("border-color", "red");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you changed `yourDivSelector` with the actual name of the `div` you want to target?